# A single word for non-unique?

Tags: naming

A naming question:

> I am aware that this question is about use of English, and at first thought should be asked in the English sub, but people there don't like questions like this, so I am trying my luck here...

I have a bunch of non-unique values:

```
   const nonUnique = getSomeValues();
```

now I want to make sure I have only unique ones:

```
   const unique = keepUnique(nonUnique);
```

How else can I name `nonUnique` to

- preserve the meaning: a bunch of non-unique values
- avoid using negation
- have just a nice single word that is opposite to `unique` in the described sense

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **duplicates** fits good in this case.

Comment: yeah, good call